# command copy (cp) in shell

Tags: linux, shell, command-line-interface

I wanted to copy all the files that are within a directory to a subdirectory of another directory, but my problem is when I put the command `cp -R *. C src / object / actor / source /` terminal gives me `cp:`Accessing src / object / actor / source / ': Not a directory`

Comment: Can you post the exact command you are using

or is the command you typed (spaces and all) the exact thing?

Comment: You have a lot of spaces in that command line.  Are you actually typing in spaces between all the words and the slashes?  That could be your problem.  Can you also include the output of the command "ls -al src/object/actor/source" ?

Comment: I guess his command was `cp -R *.C src/object/actor/source/`, which will output `cp: target 'src/object/actor/source/' is not a directory`

Answer (score 1):

If destination does not exists, `cp` will be failed.
You should make your destination:

```
mkdir -p src/object/actor/source/
cp * src/object/actor/source/
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux/Mac OS X:

```
cp -av source/* destination
```

On windows, use xcopy:

```
XCOPY C:\source\* D:\Backup\source /s /i
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx

Answer (score 0):

what is your working directory when you punch in this command?

does it contain the destination directory tree ./src/object/actor/source

if you have the following structure `cp -r *.c /src/object/actor/source` should work

```
.--
   |
    test.c
 --
   |
    --src
         |
          --oject
                 |
                  -- actor
                          | 
                           --source
```

...

This is of course predicated on the fact that you are executing the command from `.` otherwise you need to specify the fully qualified path to the destination `/home/you/src/object/actor/source`. This is again predicated on the fact that `/home/you/src/object/actor/source` actually exists. If it doesn't then you need to `mkdir` to create the directory.